# Check caller userId and use this value from query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working with Dynamics CRM 2015 and SQL Server Reporting Services.
My task is to create a report for users having a specific security role.

My report accepts a few parameters. I need to make sure that a user not having the required security role has no access to the report parameters.

If I try create parameter with default value `=User!UserID` I get the following error:

> "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" - it is not a user id.

1. How can I find the caller's user ID?
2. How can I create a query returning the parameters only in case the calling user has the security role? I know SQL, but I never write queries like this.

Comment: The user that requests a report to ReportServer is not the same which logins against the SQL Database in all cases. To login to Sql Server you can impersonate an user, use Windows Authentication or be prompted for credentials. `User!UserID` returns the user who requests the report.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop SQL based report you can use following SQL script to get id of current user:

```
dbo.fn_FindUserGuid()
```

If you develop FetchXml based reports you will have to use query similar to following to get it:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform"
       mapping="logical" distinct="false">
   <entity name="systemuser">
      <attribute name="fullname" />
      <attribute name="systemuserid" />
      <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
      <filter type="and">
         <condition attribute="systemuserid"
                    operator="eq-userid" />
      </filter>
   </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
With your help I made target sql script, that do my task:

```
SELECT new_name, new_practiceId
FROM new_practiceBase
WHERE EXISTS
      (
       SELECT *
       FROM SystemUserRoles R
       JOIN RoleBase RB ON R.roleid=RB.roleid
       WHERE R.SystemUserId=dbo.fn_FindUserGuid()
         AND RB.name IN('Руководитель практики','Управляющий партнер')
      );
```

full query, that created Query designer:

```
SELECT        new_name, new_practiceId
FROM            new_practiceBase
WHERE        EXISTS
                             (SELECT        R.SystemUserId, R.RoleId, R.SystemUserRoleId, R.VersionNumber, RB.RoleId AS Expr1, RB.RoleTemplateId, RB.OrganizationId, RB.Name, RB.BusinessUnitId, RB.CreatedOn, RB.ModifiedOn, 
                                                         RB.CreatedBy, RB.VersionNumber AS Expr2, RB.ModifiedBy, RB.ParentRoleId, RB.OverriddenCreatedOn, RB.ImportSequenceNumber, RB.IsManaged, RB.CreatedOnBehalfBy, RB.ComponentState, 
                                                         RB.RoleIdUnique, RB.SolutionId, RB.OverwriteTime, RB.ModifiedOnBehalfBy, RB.IsCustomizable, RB.SupportingSolutionId, RB.ParentRootRoleId
                               FROM            SystemUserRoles AS R INNER JOIN
                                                         RoleBase AS RB ON R.RoleId = RB.RoleId
                               WHERE        (R.SystemUserId = dbo.fn_FindUserGuid()) AND (RB.Name IN ('Руководитель практики', 'Управляющий партнер')))
```